# Efficient perfect matching algorithm for even number of vertices?

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching

What is the most efficient algorithm for detecting if there exists a perfect matching in a graph with even number of vertices ?

Comment: Edmond's algorithm? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_general_graphs

Comment: @NiklasB  Edmond's algorithm not only detects but also gives a way to find out such a perfect matching. Is there is some other algo with less time complexity to just know about existence ?

Comment: I doubt that very much. Typically the decision variants of such problems are as difficult to solve as constructing a solution. I can't say for sure, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: As NiklasB pointed out, the first answer I gave is incorrect.

To correct what I said below (see [1](https://madars.org/projects/6854/AlgMatching.pdf) for a more in depth discussion of the following paragraph):
First, the Tutte matrix is a matrix of formal variables, so its determinant is a polynomial in terms of formal variables, and not a number. Since T is a formal matrix, computing its determinant could take exponential time. However, we don't need to really compute det(T) just test whether it is identically the 0 polynomial. This means that for every numerical assignment of variables in T, det(T) will yield 0. It can further be shown that if there doesn't exist a perfect matching, for *most* assignments of variables, det(T) will evaluate to a non-zero variable. Therfore, we can substitute random values for variables in T and compute the determinant. If we evaluate to a non-zero value we can safely say that there doesn't exist a matching. Otherwise, if we repeat this a sufficient number of times, we achieve a desired confidence to say there does exist a perfect matching.

This algorithm is still bounded by the runtime of taking a determinant. The current most efficient known algorithm has a runtime of O(n^2.373), which in this case is O(|V|^2.373). What does this mean?

Edmond's has O(|E|sqrt(|V|)).

For certain types of graphs, particularly dense ones, this could actually beat Edmond's, asymptotically. But like I mentioned, this is still a randomized algorithm not an exact one.

Editorial Comment: The one benefit it has is that its significantly easier to wrap your head around an actually implement than Edmonds. Implementing Edmond's in C was one of the saddest nights of my undergraduate career.

ORIGINAL WRONG ANSWER:
You can find existence of perfect matching using the Tutte matrix:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_matrix

If A(t) is the tutte matrix of a graph G(V,E), then there exists a perfect matching iff the det(A) != 0. You can find a determinant in O(n^3) operations by gaussian elimination, which, in this case would be O(|V|sqrt(|V|)). This is an improvement over the O(|E|sqrt(|V|)) runtime of Edmonds if O(|E|) > O(|V|).

Comment: How do you arrive at the `O(|V|sqrt(|V|))` bound for the determinant? I'd say `n = |V|` and thus the time for Guassian elimination is worse than the runtime of the blossom algorithm even for dense graphs. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Whoops. You're actually right. I had misread what n is for the runtime of a determinant (I thought n = total size of matrix, not dimensions). Will update my answer to reflect that